# map url to proxy domain nginx

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I want to access https://foo.dom.com from https://dom.com/foo how should be the nginx proxy_pass rewrite rules,
Example: the access at https://foo.dom.com/bar will also be accessible at https://dom.com/foo/bar
Note also that https://foo.dom.com uses SSL and subdomain access can stay as it was

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried this https://serverfault.com/questions/379675/nginx-reverse-proxy-url-rewrite there are 2 issues https://dom.com/foo proxy passes to right domain but rewrites the url as https://dom.com/ ,ssl bar is not green is shown as red on https

Answer (score 1):

No proxying, no rewriting. Just add another server block with a different root directory.

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name dom.com;
    ssl_certificate ...
    ssl_certificate_key ...
    root /var/www/dom.com/html;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name foo.dom.com;
    ssl_certificate ...
    ssl_certificate_key ...
    root /var/www/dom.com/html/foo;
}
```

Comment: I can only use proxy because they are not on my server @miknik